# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED with sll apache2.4

Tags: apache, ssl, iptables, ufw

I'm having a problem while trying to use my ssl certificate on apache 2.4
Chrome continue to respond with : ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
If i try on command line :

```
   openssl s_client -connect localhost:443 -state -debug
   connect: Connection refused
   connect:errno=111
```

I also try to check what's wrong with 443 port on firewall :

```
netstat -pant | grep httpd
```

doesn't answer answer anithing

```
ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

nmap give this feedback

```
nmap localhost

Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-12-13 21:52 CET
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.0000050s latency).
Not shown: 997 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
53/tcp   open  domain
3306/tcp open  mysql

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.58 seconds
```

if this can help you, i generated my certificate with let's encrypt using the -w webroot option this other one, wasn't ok

in apache i already enabled aendmod ssl
    a2enmod ssl
    Considering dependency setenvif for ssl:
    Module setenvif already enabled
    Considering dependency mime for ssl:
    Module mime already enabled
    Considering dependency socache_shmcb for ssl:
    Module socache_shmcb already enabled
    Module ssl already enabled

My vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin contact@domaine.fr
    ServerName domain.net
    ServerAlias www.domain.net

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.net/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.net/chain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.net/privkey.pem
    ...
```

My ports.conf

```
Listen 80

<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `VirtualHost` appears to be missing the `SSLEngine` directive. Try adding `SSLEngine on`.

See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslengine

Comment: hi, I tried it before, and forgot to put in in my question but even if i add it: still the same problem:

        <VirtualHost *:443>
  SSLEngine On